# The most useful User-Defined Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Do you have any aggregate functions that you have implemented because the standard ones were not good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An aggregate function for SQL Server that produces **a comma-separated list of values**.

```
Title
-----------------
The Hobbit
The Two Towers       -->   The Hobbit, The Two Towers, Leaf by Niggle
Leaf by Niggle
```

Here's my implementation: [A SQL CLR user-defined aggregate - notes on creating and debugging](http://chopeen.blogspot.com/2007/05/sql-clr-user-defined-aggregate-notes-on.html)

Comment: Very useful. I have this too. I called it toCSV, but I don't really like that name. What did you call yours? Any better ideas?

Comment: @PAUL Mansour I named mine `Concat` (short for *concatenate*), but it's not a perfect name either.

Comment: SQL Server has some interesting string concatenation performance. Here's some performance tests between `select @var = @var + column` style SQL and a user-defined aggregate using a .NET `StringBuilder`: [graphs](http://imgur.com/a/MRcha) SQL-based concat gets dramatically slower once the total string length goes over 500k chars.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In Oracle I've implemented a kind of group_concat because it is unavailable in Oracle. I've made a couple different versions which do a simple concat with comma-delimiting strings. Another does the same, only sorted. And there's another one that doesn't use a comma, but a special character so the results can be processed more easily when the values themselves might contain comma's too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Weighted Average
2. PercentAcross - This is the sum of X where a condition is true, divided by the sum of X.